# How do I Plot tangent line equation on the given point on the same axes?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

How can I plot 1st, 2nd, 3rd derivatives and the tangent line equation on the 
   given point on a single graph?

f(x)= x^(3) - 2x, x = -1

```
f[x_] := [[x^(3)-2x, x],{x-> -1}]
```

Below is the tangent line equation on a given point code:

```
 *In* : Collect[Normal[Series[f[x], {x, a, 1}]], x, Simplify]
 *Out*: 2 + x
```

Below is the Plot code containing 1st, 2nd, and 3rd Derivatives,but how can I add the tangent line equation graph into the line below?

```
Plot[{f[x],f'[x],f''[x], f'''[x]},{x},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

Comment: I'll reopen if you can explain why the answer to your previous question does not answer this one as well.

Comment: @J.M. I’m sorry, it was very complicated for me to grasp what was written. I did manage to figure out how to find the tangent line however I’m still have problem with plotting the tangent line and others on one graph. I’m very new to this. Sorry about the troubles

Comment: Then, please leave a comment on David's answer asking him to clarify, or edit your previous question to explain why you have trouble with David's answer.